# Function Continuous on Induced Topology if and only if Function Continuous

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Let $(X, \mathcal{T}_X)$, $(Y, \mathcal{T}_Y)$ be topological spaces, $f : X \to Y$ is a function and $U \subset X$ is a nonempty open subset. I want to show that (1) $f|_U : (U, \mathcal{T}_X|_U) \to (Y, \mathcal{T}_Y)$ is continuous if and only if (2) $f : (X, \mathcal{T}_X) \to \mathcal{T}_Y)$ is continuous at every $x \in U$.

My attempt is as follows:

(1) $\Rightarrow$ (2): Assume that $f|_U$ is continuous. Then we want to show that $f$ is continuous at every $x \in U$. Let $x \in U$ be arbitrary. Since $f|_U$ is continuous, then for all $V \in \mathcal{T}_Y$, $f|_U^{-1}(V) = U \cap f^{-1}(V)$ is open and is also nonempty as well, and since $x \in U$, $f$ is continuous.

(2) $\Rightarrow$ (1): Assume that $f$ is continuous at $x \in U$. We want to show that $f|_U$ is continuous. Let $x \in U$. Since $f$ is continuous, then for all $V \in \mathcal{T}_Y$ containing $f(x)$, there exists a $W \in \mathcal{T}_X$ containing $x \in W$ such that $f(W) \subset V$. Take $W = f(U) \cap V$ to be such that $f|_U^{-1}(f(U) \cap V) = f|_U^{-1}(f(U)) \cap f|_U^{-1}(V) = (U \cap f^{-1}(f(U))) \cap (U \cap f^{-1}(V)) = U \cap f^{-1}(V)$.

Am I approaching the problem correctly? I would appreciate some suggestions on what can be improved here.

Comment: Your proofs seem unclear to me. In $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$, it is not true that $U\cap f^{-1}(V)$is non-empty in general. Also, how does this show that $f$ is continuous at $x$? You really want to start with an arbitrary neighbourhood of $f(x)$, and find a neighbourhood of $x$ mapping into the former. Here, of course, the preimage will work, but you need to be a lot clearer about what you are doing.
In $(2)\Rightarrow (1)$, the method is also unclear to me. You want to show that an *arbitrary* preimage of an open set under $f|_U$ is open, but it looks like you are doing it with a specific set.

Comment: Also be consistent in your notation. In $(2)\Rightarrow (1)$, you use $W\in \mathcal{T}_X$ to begin with, and later $W$ actually lives in $\mathcal{T}_Y$, where before it was $V$. This only adds to the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right ideas, but you do not properly elaborate them.

$(1) \implies (2)$: Assume that $f \mid_U$ is continuous. We have to show that for each $x \in U$ and each open neighborhood $V \in \mathcal T_Y$ of $f(x)$ there exists an open neighborhood $W \in \mathcal T_X$ of $x$ such that $f(W) \subset V$. In your proof you take $V \in \mathcal T_Y$, but do not require $f(x) \in V$.
Since $V \in \mathcal T_Y$ and $f \mid_U$ is  continuous, we know that $W = (f \mid_U)^{-1}(V)$ is open in $U$. Since $U$ is open in $X$, $W$ is also open on $X$. Note that $U$ being open in $X$ is essential here; you did not use this fact at all. Since $x \in U$ and $f \mid_U(x) = f(x) \in V$ and, we see that $x \in W$. But because $W \subset U$ we get $f(W) = f \mid_U(W) =  f \mid_U((f \mid_U)^{-1}(V)) \subset V$.

$(2) \implies (1)$: Assume that $f$ is continuous at **all** $x \in U$. We have to show that $(f \mid_U)^{-1}(V) = f^{-1}(V) \cap U$ is open in $U$ for all $V \in \mathcal T_Y$. So let $x \in f^{-1}(V) \cap U$. Since $x \in U$, we know that $f$ is continuous at $x$. Since $f(x) \in V$, there exists an open neighborhood $W \in \mathcal T_X$ of $x$ such that $f(W) \subset V$. Then $W_x = W \cap U$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $U$ (recall the definition of subspace topology; note that here we do not have to require that $U$ is open in $X$). Since $f(W_x) \subset V$ is equivalent to $W_x \subset f^{-1}(V)$, we get $x \in W_x =  W \cap U \subset f^{-1}(V) \cap U$. This shows that $f^{-1}(V) \cap U$ is the union of open subsets $W_x$ of $U$, thus it is open in $U$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it makes more sense to me now.